# Java MemoryMXBean Used Memory bigger than Max

Tags: java, memory, jmx

I got an interesting effect regarding runtime memory analysis with the MemoryMXBean.
I would like to determine the Free memory in Heap together with NonHeap.
So my code looks like this:

```
static MemoryMXBean mbean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();
long fullused = mbean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed() + mbean.getNonHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed();
long fullmax = mbean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getMax() + mbean.getNonHeapMemoryUsage().getMax();
long fullfree = fullmax - fullused;
```

Sometimes the result for fullFree is a negative value.
How can that be? A race condition that some garbage collection was made after the calculation for the used mem? In my logs I see it quite often so I doubt the race condition theory.
Any other thoughts here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Max for NonHeap can be -1. You can check that via jconsole for your application. 
In hotspot sources calculation of memory usage is done in `jmm_GetMemoryUsage` method. If one of non heap memory pools has undefined max size, than max size in entire non heap will be -1. Metaspace pool (without MaxMetaspaceSize command flag) has undefined max size

Comment: Thanx, I will build in a check for that.